# Trouble using ManagedProperty

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, managed-bean

I'm trying to share an object between several SessionScoped beans. I get errors though and I really don't know why.

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{tb}")
private testBean tb;
```

I believe that this is the right syntax, but any call like `tb.getName` results in an exception.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "tb")
public class testBean 
{
    private String name = "sumthing";

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Have I completely misunderstod how ManagedProperty works?

Answer (score 2):

Probably your consumer class doesn't have setters/getters for `tb`

Answer (score 0):

Why not add `@SessionScoped` to your JavaBean? See my explanation to this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526145/java-terms-and-random-words-clarification/5526305#5526305).
Secondly, you don't do `#{tb.getName}`, rather use EL Expression `#{tb.name}` instead.

Comment: It is declared SessoNScoped in the faces-config. Although from some testing I think it might be a problem with the library as I noticed that tb was null.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at the Flash scope, the idea is to use this if you just want to pass values/objects from one view to another, and you don't want to burden the server with a session state.

For an example see: http://jugojava.blogspot.com/2011/06/jsf2-flash-scope-example.html